# MongoDB distinct values on subdocuments

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework, distinct-values

I have a little weird  database structure it is as follows:

I have a document with normal properties, then I have a metadata property which is an array of objects.

```
metadata: {[
  {
     key: [key],
     value: [value]
  },
  ...
 ]}
```

**Edit**: There will never be a metadata sub-document which has a duplicate key

It was done this way to retain the order of the metadata objects

Now I want to get distinct values of a metadata object with a given key.

I want to find every distinct [value] where [key] = "x" using MongoDB. And have the distinct values returned in an array (not the document)

I guess this is not possible using the distinct command, but is this possible using an aggregation pipeline or do I have to use Map-Reduce?

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I presume you mean this:

```js
{
    "metadata": [
        { "key": "abc", "value": "borf" },
        { "key": "cdc", "value": "biff" }
    ]
},
{
    "metadata": [
        { "key": "bbc", "value": "barf" },
        { "key": "abc", "value": "borf" },
        { "key": "abc", "value": "barf" }
    ]
}
```

Where if you filter for "abc" and get the distinct "value" entries like this:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "metadata.key": "abc" } },
    { "$unwind": "$metadata" },
    { "$match": { "metadata.key": "abc" } },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$metadata.value"
    }}
])
```

Or even better:

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "metadata.key": "abc" } },
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": [ { "$ifNull": [ "$key", "abc" ] }, "abc" ] },
            "then": "$$DESCEND",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$metadata" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$metadata.value",
        "count": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Which would basically give:

```js
{ "_id": "barf", "count": 1 },
{ "_id": "borf", "count": 2 }
```

But it is **not possible** for this to just be an array of "barf" and "borf". The `distinct()` method does an array of keys only, but it is also very limited. Therefore it can only do this:

```js
db.collection.distinct("metadata.value",{ "metadata.key": "abc" })
[ "biff", "borf", "barf" ]
```

Which is incorrect as a result. So just take the "document" results from above and apply some "post processing":

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    { "$match": { "metadata.key": "abc" } },
    { "$redact": {
        "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": [ { "$ifNull": [ "$key", "abc" ] }, "abc" ] },
            "then": "$$DESCEND",
            "else": "$$PRUNE"
        }
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$metadata" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$metadata.value"
    }}
]).map(function(doc) {
    return doc._id;
})
```

And that result is a plain array of just the distinct values:

```js
[ "borf", "barf" ]
```

Comment: Wow thanks for this quick and in-depth answer! One thing I forgot to mention was that there will never be a duplicate key in a metdata subdocument. Guess I gotta read up some more on the MongoDB documentation.

Comment: @FelixSchoeler The `_id` in the [**`$group`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) demands that all "grouping keys" are reduced to "unique" values. So no. And there is at least one link to documentation right there.

Comment: What I meant was that per metadata array in the source collection, will there never be an Object which has the same key as another Object in the same metadata array. So the second `"abc"` key in the second `"metadata"` array would never occur. But your code works like a charm for me :)

Comment: @FelixSchoeler Well you should be able to see that to the listing here there is absolutely no difference if there was or if their wasn't. Your question was for he distinct values of a given key. In lack of an example I made up some data. But it still makes no dfference to the outcome as all documents are denormalized.